# Fixed Point Notation (in Register)

Tags: fixed-point, real-number

As you know, fractional part of fixed point notation is can be different for different register. So, how is the fractional part determined according to the register bit address?

```
 8 bits =  1 sign bit + 4 bits  (integral) + 3 bits (fractional part)
16 bits =  1 sign bit + 9 bits  (integral) + 6 bits (fractional part)
32 bits =  1 sign bit + 15 bits (integral) + 9 bits (fractional part)
```

In here, for 32 bit register consist of **"15 bit for integral part"**, **"9 bit for fractional part"**, so if 128 bit register what will be happened? I searched to see if there was a formula for this, but I couldn't find the **formula** I wanted.

Also, another question is that, in programming language, example in C, is fixed point used any datatype? For example, "int16_t" data-type can be used for fractional part?

Comment: The position of the fixed point is not determined by the size of the register. You can have a 32 bit (signed) fixed point register with 1 fractional bit or 18 fractional bits or whatever you like (between 0 and 31). I suppose the answer to your question is that it's determined by whatever convention this part of your codebase uses

Comment: So why does the documentation say that 8 bit register 1 indicates sign, 4 indicates integer and 3 bit indicates fractional integer? @PaulHankin Example [link](https://www.tutorialandexample.com/fixed-and-floating-point-number)

Comment: The description at that link doesn't look very good.  You just use however many bits for each part as you need.  E.g. I've been playing around with NTP lately and they effectively have 64 bit timestamps, 32bits for integer part, 32 for the fraction, no sign bit.

Comment: Either that site is talking about some specific system that uses particular fixed points for different register sizes, it's just an example, or it's wrong. Based on a quick skim of that site Ifound a few mistakes and some weird writing I wouldn't use it to learn programming.

Comment: In NTP with v4 used floating point notation, it is not used fixed point for current version. @SamMason

Comment: My mind is very confused for a simple subject. Another sample [link](https://www.codingninjas.com/studio/library/fixed-and-floating-point-representation) @PaulHankin, Although fixed point is a simpler topic, I am confused due to resource constraints.

Comment: One of these sites probably copied content from the other. I wouldn't use either. If you want a free resource to learn about fixed point arithmetic, the wikipedia page seems reasonable: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something and they're talking about some cpu and they have specific fixed point operations with a given precision, but if so they should be clearer. More likely they're just full of errors -- I skimmed their pages on the C language and found a couple of things that were just wrong.

Comment: I note that some of the pages on tutorialandexample seem to be copied from javatpoint -- I found examples include that site's name. Maybe that's legit, but doesn't give a good signal about their quality control.

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki I was referring to the NTP packet layout.  Some calculations are certainly more convenient when done using floats, but the spec notes that you need to be somewhat careful when doing this to maintain precision.

Comment: @PaulHankin agreed that OP's links look a bit misleading. I've had a bit of a search and https://andybargh.com/fixed-and-floating-point-binary/ looks reasonable, while https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61c/sp06/handout/fixedpt.html focuses more on fixed-point math.  have only given them a skim, but they feel better to me.  your pointers to wikipedia seems like a good source as well

Comment: @SamMason first article seems to good. Can u help of the maximum and minimum calculation of fixed point. For example?`−2^(b−1)/2f, how can I find f value in here

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki is that from Andy's page? if so, isn't `f` just the number of bits you're using for the fractional part

Comment: Yes, so how can I find it @SamMason? "−2^(b−1)/2^f", for example for 128 bit what will be value of "f"? for this equation?

Comment: it's whatever it needs it to be! there isn't a single "correct value", it's up to you to determine based on the problem you're solving.  if you only need to represent down to quarters then a value of 2 is okay, if you need more precision then you increase it.  think about when you're writing out decimal numbers, if you're writing out numbers with, e.g., 5 significant figures do you always use the same number of fractional digits?  or do you choose something relevant.  it's the same for fixed-point maths, you choose f based on the problem you're solving